# Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type 'ReactNode'. Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type 'ReactPortal'.ts(2322)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am getting this error while trying to map an array with the object.

```
Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type 'ReactNode'.
  Type 'unknown' is not assignable to type 'ReactPortal'.ts(2322)
index.d.ts(1353, 9): The expected type comes from property 'children' which is declared here on type 'DetailedHTMLProps<HTMLAttributes<HTMLParagraphElement>, HTMLParagraphElement>'
```

Here is my code.

```js
const data = [
  {
    label: "CLIENT ID",
    value: "clientId",
  },
  {
    label: "BILLING CUSTOMER ID",
    value: "billingCustomerId",
  },
  {
    label: "EMAIL",
    value: "email",
  },
  {
    label: "PHONE NUMBER",
    value: "phoneNumber",
  },
  {
    label: "BUSINESS NAME",
    value: "businessName",
  },
  {
    label: "BILLING ADDRESS",
    value: "billingAddress",
  },
  {
    label: "TAX DETAILS",
    value: "taxDetails",
  },
  {
    label: "LOCATION",
    value: "location",
  },
  {
    label: "LANGUAGE",
    value: "language",
  },
];
const ProfileDetail = (props: any) => {
 

 
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  useEffect(() => {
    if (clientId !== null && userMasterId !== null && accessToken !== null) {
     
      clientDetail(accessToken, clientId);
    }
  }, [clientId, userMasterId, accessToken]);
  const profileState: any = useSelector((state: any) => state.profileBilling);
  const clientDetail = async (aToken: string, cId: string) => {
    await dispatch(getClientDetailThunk(aToken, cId));
  };

  return (
    <div>
      {data.map((item: any, i: number) => {
        return (
          <Box marginY={2} key={item.label}>
            <Typography className={classes.menuTitle}>{item.label}</Typography>
            <p className={classes.menuSubtitle}>
              {item.value === Object.keys(profileState?.cDetail)[i].     // I tried to map the array value like this so that i don't have to repeat this block of code.
                ? Object.values(profileState?.cDetail)[i]
                :  null}
            </p>
          </Box>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
};

export default ProfileDetail;
```

I am not sure if i am doing it write or wrong. But the code is working on UI but it is showing the typescript error which i am not sure how to resolve.

This how profileState.cDetail looks like.

```
{
billingAddress: "Street2",
billingCustomerId: "cus_Kf4ylZZmyALR6f",
businessName: "xxxxxxx",
clientId: "67f3b1f6",
email: "xxxxxxx@xxxxx.com",
language: "English",
location: "xxxx",
phoneNumber: "1234123412",
taxDetails: "123",
}
```